# How can I find the position of a substring (list values) in a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, string

#python
My data frame has one column:

```
User name
XYZ (R1)
ABCD (R2) 
LKMNP (R2)
```

I want to find the position of R1, R2 and R2 in the data frame and then remove them. The output should be:

```
User name   extract  Position  New name      
XYZ (R1)    R1       5         XYZ
ABCD (R2)   R2       6         ABCD
LK (R2)     R2       4         LK
```

Comment: What's the condition of substring and how do you want to remove it ?

Comment: @Psidom I edited the column name to New Name if Remove was confusing

Comment: No I meant how do you determine,  `R1`, `R2` and `R3` are to be removed ? Is it  because they are enclosed in parenthesis  ?

Comment: It is because they start with parenthesis + has the word R + has a number + close the parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split` or `str.extract`:

```
df['New name'] = df['User name'].str.split(r' (', regex=False).str[0]
# OR
df['New name'] = df['User name'].str.extract(r'([^ \(]+)')
print(df)

# Output
    User name New name
0    XYZ (R1)      XYZ
1   ABCD (R2)     ABCD
2  LKMNP (R2)    LKMNP
```

**Update**

> The regex condition is : it start with parenthesis ( + has the word R + has a number + close the parenthesis )

```
df[['new name', 'extract', 'position']] = (
    df['User name'].str.extract(r'([^\s\(]+) \((R\d+)\)')
                   .assign(pos=lambda x: x[0].str.len() + 2)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    User name new name extract  position
0    XYZ (R1)      XYZ      R1         5
1   ABCD (R2)     ABCD      R2         6
2  LKMNP (R2)    LKMNP      R2         7
```

Comment: It helps. What change do I need to make if I just need new name and not extract and position columns. The initial space and check of digit condition is important as someone can have a user name of L(RK)

Comment: Like one of the user name is #1 Winner

Comment: @tejkiran. Is it what you are looking for `df['User name'].str.extract(r'(.*)\s\(R\d+')`?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
# extract 3 parts
df[['new name', 'position', 'extract']] = df['User name'].str.extract(r'(\S+)(\s+\()([^\)]+)')

# use first 2 to compute the Rx position
df['position'] = (df[['new name', 'position']]
                  .stack().str.len()
                  .groupby(level=0).sum()
                  )
```

Output:

```
    User name  new name  extract  position
0    XYZ (R1)       XYZ       R1         5
1   ABCD (R2)      ABCD       R2         6
2  LKMNP (R2)     LKMNP       R2         7
```

Regex:

```
(\S+)      # group 1: non-space char(s)
(\s+\()    # group 2: space(s) and literal "("
([^\)]+)   # group 3: non ")" char (s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` with a function based on `re` to get what you want

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

CUSTOM_REGEX = re.compile(r'^(.*)(\(.*\))(.*)')

def find_and_delete_sub(s):
    c = CUSTOM_REGEX.match(s)
    if c is not None:
        return c.span(2)[0] + 1, c.group(1) + c.group(3)
    return None, None

pd.concat([df,
           pd.DataFrame(
             df['User Name'].map(find_and_delete_sub).tolist(),
             columns=["position", 'New Name'])], 
          axis=1)
```

Supposing that your input dataframe `df` is:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['XYZ (R1)'],
        ['ABCD (R2)'],
        ['LK (R2)'],
        ['LKMN ('],
    ],
    columns=['User Name'],
)
```

you get:

```bash
   User Name  position New Name
0   XYZ (R1)       4.0     XYZ 
1  ABCD (R2)       5.0    ABCD 
2    LK (R2)       3.0      LK 
3    LKMNP (       NaN     None
```